# d3.polygonContains always returns false

Tags: javascript, d3.js, point-in-polygon

In my `react application`, I've drawn a `polygon` by using some points and then I'm trying to find out if mouse current location is inside the polygon or not. I'm using [d3.polygonContains](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon) and passing it points array with current location points but **it always returns false**, although points are inside polygon.

here is an example;

```js
let points = [
            [ 42.34624, -71.06024 ],
            [ 42.33558, -71.06616 ],
            [ 42.32632, -71.05835 ],
            [ 42.32987, -71.05428 ],
            [ 42.34732, -71.05432 ],
            [ 42.34618, -71.05973 ],
            [ 42.34624, -71.06024 ]
        ];
        
let testPoint = [
    [42.33288, -71.05835]

];
alert(d3.polygonContains(points, testPoint));

alert(d3.polygonContains(points, (42.33288, -71.05835)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here??

Comment: `let testPoint = [42.33288, -71.05835];` and `alert(d3.polygonContains(points, [42.33288, -71.05835]));`

Comment: Regarding the current close vote: this is not a *typo* question, since the documentation is far from clear about the first argument of `d3.polygonContains`.

Comment: exactly.. and I've not find any question/ answer related to this array issue..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`testPoints` itself must be a simple array with 2 elements, with `x` and `y` positions in that order, not an array with an inner array:

```
let testPoint = [42.33288, -71.05835];
```

Unfortunately the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon#polygonContains) are not explicitly clear about this, it just says:

> d3.polygonContains(polygon, point)
>
> Returns true if and only if the specified point is inside the specified polygon.

But one can always inspect the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon/blob/0c8929bfd341f4ec5c899bbf94948d807cef8957/src/contains.js#L1):

```
export default function(polygon, point) {
  var n = polygon.length,
      p = polygon[n - 1],
      x = point[0], y = point[1],
      //^-- here we see that 'point' is an array with 2 elements
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
let points = [
  [42.34624, -71.06024],
  [42.33558, -71.06616],
  [42.32632, -71.05835],
  [42.32987, -71.05428],
  [42.34732, -71.05432],
  [42.34618, -71.05973],
  [42.34624, -71.06024]
];

let testPoint = [42.33288, -71.05835];

console.log(d3.polygonContains(points, testPoint));
console.log(d3.polygonContains(points, [42.33288, -71.05835]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```